# Unable to open camera in Android studio Emulator after Upgrading to Android 12

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, android-camera, android-12

I am new to Android studio(Java) I was using Android 7 sdk 27 and every thing was working fine, but after upgrading to Android 12 sdk 31 version with the code there were some conditions to be added for permission for camera options to request permission now popup for permission is shown but camera is not opening in emulator is it regular issue in Android 12 version or do i need to add any code in java for camera to on?